# Why can't I have CiviEvents without dates?

Tags: civievent

Incremental and iterative planning and development is the modern way. In CiviEvent I can't create events that have no date. To me that would be a first step in a planning process, creating the event with a brief description, then later add a date and more information.

I could even see uses of having public events without dates. That creates visibility into what might be coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes sense to me that you might want to do it that way, unfortunately CiviEvent does not allow it as it is now. Can you add your enhancement request on the CiviCRM issue tracker? (https://issues.civicrm.org/)

Comment: Added https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-4464

Comment: This link is to something about event templates and seems to be open and closed in 2009 and, to me, is not the same thing as being asked for. In some situations the template is what is wanted (planning an event) but not for an event that you want to be public. I my case I want to get people signed up before the date(s) are fixed.

Comment: That link is obviously wrong. Maybe something odd happened in the archiving and move to GitLab. Unfortunately I can't find the issue at all in GitLab. Maybe it's time to create another one.